# SQL query for point-in-polygon using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, gis, rdbms, postgis

I have the following simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_test
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  poly polygon NOT NULL
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
```

I then try to insert a row with a polygon:

```
insert into tbl_test values(1, PolyFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 10 10, 10 0, 0 0))'))
```

And run into this error:

> column "poly" is of type polygon but expression is of type geometry

Which is lame. So my first questions is:

1. Do I really have to cast?

Anyway, after casting it works. And now I'm trying to do a simple ST_Contains query:

```
select id, poly from tbl_test where ST_Contains(poly, Point(GeomFromText('POINT(9 2)')))
```

Which gives the error:

```
ERROR:  function st_contains(polygon, point) does not exist
LINE 1: select id, poly from tbl_test where ST_Contains(poly, Point(...
                                            ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

What am I supposed to do?

The following works:

```
select st_contains(st_geomfromtext('POLYGON((0 0, 10 10, 10 0, 0 0))'), st_geomfromtext('POINT(0 0)'))
```

But that's probably because both arguments are of type Geometry. The actual query against the table data doesn't work.

**Answer:**

Doi! The problem was that the DB I created was not based on the postgis template DB (and therefor did not have the relevant functions and geometry column tables, etc.).
May I just remark, in conclusion, that the way PostGIS requires you to add hundreds of functions, rows and a few tables to your DB just so you'd have GIS support is completely lame. It makes backup of the schema that much more complex and is very error prone (heaven forbid if you neglect to call AddGeometryColumn and just add a geometry column yourself).

Comment: If poly in poly works, why not make a "1-gon" polygon with the point you're trying to find?

Comment: I'm not sure polygons of 1 point are supported in postgres. Besides, it's a workaround for a problem I'm not sure exists..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The polygon is a fundamental Postgres type which PostGIS builds on top of.  You enable the geometry columns with the PostGIS function `select AddGeometryColumn(...)`.  Otherwise you are working with straight polygons:

```
=> create table gt (id int, space polygon);
=> insert into gt values (1, '((2,2),(3,4),(3,6),(1,1))');
INSERT 0 1
=> select point(space) from gt where id = 1;
    point    
-------------
 (2.25,3.25)
(1 row)
```

This is the center point of the polygon

```
=> select circle(space) from gt where id = 1;
             circle             
--------------------------------
 <(2.25,3.25),1.93994028704315>
(1 row)
```

This is the minimum bounding circle of the polygon, expressed as a Postgres `circle` type.  All the geometric operators are documented [here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/functions-geometry.html](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/functions-geometry.html)  The base polygon does not have any projection data, SRID, etc., so if it works with PostGIS it is probably just defaulting to presets and getting lucky.  But of course there are tons of cases where you simply need geometry on a sub-geospatial scale.

Comment: Is there a page the summarizes the difference between PostGIS and native geometrical data support in PG? The data I'm keeping is geographical (2D), and I'm not sure whether or not I really need PostGIS.

Comment: I really like PostGIS, certainly it will give you more options in the long run, will let you interact with qgis or even esri, and implements millions of features (special rules for Finnish and Swedish government data, etc.).  As to how PostGIS uses and diverges from the other Postgres types, that sounds like a question for SO.  Couldn't find a clear explanation googling, or looking just now through the postgis source.

Comment: I think that http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/datatype-geometric.html and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-geometry.html provide a fairly clear overview of all of the standard Postgres geometry types and functions. Anything outside of that is PostGIS.

Answer (score 9):

Ok, weird, I found out the following much simpler syntax works:

```
insert into tbl_test (poly) values ('(0,0),(0,10),(10, 10), (0, 0)')

select * from tbl_test where poly @> '(2, 8)'
```

But I'm struggling to figure out the difference between these sets of functions and operators. Does this shorter syntax (which isn't really OpenGIS compliant) take advantage of the same spatial indexes, etc.?

Comment: I know its very old question...but it seems you have very good idea about opengis and postgre....can you tell me if i can query like find if a point is there in "any" of polygons. like 'select poly from poly_table where point(x,y)'

Comment: @JigarShah, two things.  1, it's "postgres" and secondly that's exactly what the query does.