# Postgresql Database with Longitude and Latitude

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

Im just wondering if one can make an spatial database using postgres + postGIS wherein the user can query each city in the world then get the their real coordinates(latitude&longitude) in the resulting set.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023229/spatial-data-in-postgresql

Comment: and is there a downloadable database that contains all places in the world together with their coordinates in the globe?

Comment: Maxmind has free world Geo database.

Comment: If you want to just query for the name and return coordinates you don't need PostGIS for that.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of available data sets out there.

I would assume, that [GeoNames](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/) is most appropriate here. This project extracts all objects from Wikipedia, that has coordinates specified. And of  course, it is quite possible to query cities.

If you need more detailed info, then all depends on a particular country. Say, Netherlands state authorities can provide you extracts of the [state estate database](http://www.kadaster.nl/BAG), which includes all buildings, inhabited places, living boats and some more.

I assume that building a complete list of cities will be a costy project.

Comment: Are you aware of a similar service to 'state estate database' in the UK?

Comment: @jawr, Something [here](https://www.gov.uk/government/statistical-data-sets), perhaps...