# How to search for all points inside all polygons in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I want to search for all points of a specific user inside all polygons and display the polygons

these are my tables

```
users 

 id   points 
 1     1
 1     2
 1     3
 1     4
 2     3
 3     1

 poly

  polygon-points    poly-name
  (1,2,4,5)          store
  (1,3)              shoop
```

I wrote this code

```
BEGIN
FOR poly-name IN SELECT poly-name FROM poly

LOOP
    FOR points IN SELECT * FROM users
    LOOP
    points@poly-name
    END LOOP;

END LOOP;
RETURN;
END
```

Comment: Are you using PostGIS? Or built-in PostgreSQL shape data types? You've failed to provide table definitinos, so it's hard to know.

Comment: do you mean the types of the polygon-points and the points ?

the type of polygon-points is polygon and points is point

Comment: I found a function that I cloud use which is 
    boolean ST_Crosses(geometry g1, geometry g2);

but the problem is I want to use this function between a point and a polygon
so how i can cast the point and the polygon to geometry since this what i read when i googled the problem

Comment: Is the column polygon-points defined as a 'geometry' or 'geography' data type, or are you using a varchar field and storing it as an array?  You can use st_geomfromtext to create a polygon in a geometry field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are using PostgreSQL's built-in `point` and `polygon` types, but you want to use a PostGIS function [`ST_Crosses`](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/ST_Crosses.html) that takes the PostGIS `geometry` type as arguments.

If so, start here: [SQL query for point-in-polygon using PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012504/sql-query-for-point-in-polygon-using-postgresql)

Note that PostGIS is an add-on to PostgreSQL. You may not have it installed, and may need to install it to get the `ST_Crosses` function (and a *lot* more).