# Creating a table for Polygon values in Postgis and inserting

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have the following area "name" and "polygon" values for 10 different areas
('A',50.6373 3.0750,50.6374 3.0750,50.6374 3.0749,50.63 3.07491,50.6373 3.0750)

I want to create a table in postgres DB using POSTGIS

Later, I will have lan and lat values (e.g. 50.5465 3.0121) in a table to compare with the above table and pull out the area name

Can you help me with the code for both creating and inserting the polygon coordinates?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment you question, there is a link you might find useful: [SQL query for point-in-polygon using PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012504/sql-query-for-point-in-polygon-using-postgresql)

Adding extension for your database

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

Creating table

```
CREATE TABLE areas (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(64),
    polygon GEOMETRY
);
```

Creating index over polygon field

```
CREATE INDEX areas_polygon_idx ON areas USING GIST (polygon);
```

Inserting record

```
INSERT INTO areas (name, polygon) VALUES (
    'A',
    ST_GeometryFromText('POLYGON((50.6373 3.0750,50.6374 3.0750,50.6374 3.0749,50.63 3.07491,50.6373 3.0750))')
);
```

Querying

```
SELECT name FROM areas WHERE ST_Contains(polygon, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(50.637 3.074)'));
 name 
------
(0 rows)

SELECT name FROM areas WHERE ST_Contains(polygon, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(50.63735 3.07495)'));
 name 
------
 A
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot icuken. This is really helpful!!